# adding new features to gtf file from tab separated file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

[GTF](https://asia.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/gff.html) file is a file format used for genomic annotation

I'm using this script which is basically reading a reference file that contains my column of interest and a gtf file where I have to match feature and then add the new feature alongside the mapped feature.

My gtf file

```
cat Canis_lupus_familiaris.ROS_Cfam_1.0.108.gtf | head
#!genome-build ROS_Cfam_1.0
#!genome-version ROS_Cfam_1.0
#!genome-date 2020-09
#!genome-build-accession GCA_014441545.1
#!genebuild-last-updated 2020-10
X       ensembl gene    24550462        24552226        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845015183"; gene_version "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding";
X       ensembl transcript      24550462        24552226        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845015183"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "ENSCAFT00845027108"; transcript_version "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; tag "Ensembl_canonical";
X       ensembl exon    24552206        24552226        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845015183"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "ENSCAFT00845027108"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; exon_id "ENSCAFE00845128634"; exon_version "1"; tag "Ensembl_canonical";
X       ensembl CDS     24552206        24552226        .       -       0       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845015183"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "ENSCAFT00845027108"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; protein_id "ENSCAFP00845021332"; protein_version "1"; tag "Ensembl_canonical";
X       ensembl start_codon     24552224        24552226        .       -       0       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845015183"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "ENSCAFT00845027108"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; tag "Ensembl_canonical";
```

My reference file here The column named **Entrez_ID** is the new attribute which I want to add to the gtf file.

```
gene_id Entrez_ID
ENSCAFG00845006432 399518
ENSCAFG00845002136 399530
ENSCAFG00845029798 399544
ENSCAFG00845011460 399545
ENSCAFG00845001610 399653
ENSCAFG00845013158 403157
ENSCAFG00845014982 403168
ENSCAFG00845021967 403170
ENSCAFG00845019241 403400
```

My desired example output

```
#!genome-build ROS_Cfam_1.0
#!genome-version ROS_Cfam_1.0
#!genome-date 2020-09
#!genome-build-accession GCA_014441545.1
#!genebuild-last-updated 2020-10
X       ensembl gene    24550462        24552226        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845006432"; gene_version "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; Entrez_ID "399518";
X       ensembl transcript      24550462        24552226        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845006432"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "ENSCAFT00845027108"; transcript_version "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; tag "Ensembl_canonical"; Entrez_ID "399518";
X       ensembl exon    24552206        24552226        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845006432"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "ENSCAFT00845027108"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; exon_id "ENSCAFE00845128634"; exon_version "1"; tag "Ensembl_canonical"; Entrez_ID "399518";
X       ensembl CDS     24552206        24552226        .       -       0       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845006432"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "ENSCAFT00845027108"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; protein_id "ENSCAFP00845021332"; protein_version "1"; tag "Ensembl_canonical"; Entrez_ID "399518";
X       ensembl start_codon     24552224        24552226        .       -       0       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845006432"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "ENSCAFT00845027108"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; tag "Ensembl_canonical"; Entrez_ID "399518";
```

My script

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file="$1"
gff_file="$2"
output_file="$3"

# Create a temporary file for storing the intermediate results
temp_file=$(mktemp)

# Function to append temporary file contents to output file
cleanup() {
    if [[ -f "$temp_file" ]]; then
        cat "$temp_file" >> "$output_file"
        rm "$temp_file"
    fi
}

# Trap termination signals and execute cleanup function
trap cleanup EXIT TERM

# Read the input file line by line
while IFS=$'\t' read -r gene_id Entrez_ID; do
    # Search for the corresponding line in the GFF file and append the annotation
    awk -v id="$gene_id" -v eid="$Entrez_ID" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} $0 ~ id { sub(/;$/, "; Entrez_ID \"" eid "\";", $0) } 1' "$gff_file" >> "$temp_file"
done < "$input_file"

# Combine the original GFF file with the annotated lines and store the result in the output file
cat "$temp_file" > "$output_file"

# Clean up the temporary file
cleanup

echo "Mapping and annotation complete. Output file: $output_file"
```

The output I'm getting is this

```
cat output.gtf | head
#!genome-build ROS_Cfam_1.0
#!genome-version ROS_Cfam_1.0
#!genome-date 2020-09
#!genome-build-accession GCA_014441545.1
#!genebuild-last-updated 2020-10
X       ensembl gene    24550462        24552226        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845015183"; gene_version "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; Entrez_ID "Entrez_ID";
X       ensembl transcript      24550462        24552226        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845015183"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "ENSCAFT00845027108"; transcript_version "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; tag "Ensembl_canonical"; Entrez_ID "Entrez_ID";
X       ensembl exon    24552206        24552226        .       -       .       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845015183"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "ENSCAFT00845027108"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; exon_id "ENSCAFE00845128634"; exon_version "1"; tag "Ensembl_canonical"; Entrez_ID "Entrez_ID";
X       ensembl CDS     24552206        24552226        .       -       0       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845015183"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "ENSCAFT00845027108"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; protein_id "ENSCAFP00845021332"; protein_version "1"; tag "Ensembl_canonical"; Entrez_ID "Entrez_ID";
X       ensembl start_codon     24552224        24552226        .       -       0       gene_id "ENSCAFG00845015183"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "ENSCAFT00845027108"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "ensembl"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; tag "Ensembl_canonical"; Entrez_ID "Entrez_ID";
```

It doesn't append the **Entrez_ID** numerical value as shown in my expected output shown above.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

I want to know what is the blunder Im committing here .

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should define what algorithm you want to do instead of showing just your code.  You want to add a new attribute, following what logic?  When I compare your Canis_lupus_familiaris.ROS_Cfam_1.0.108.gtf file with your desired output, I see that the gene_id changed AND the new column is added.  And the gene_id in Canis_lupus_familiaris.ROS_Cfam_1.0.108.gtf does not appear in your reference file.  What algorithm is used then?

Comment: @Nic3500 thank you for commenting so here My objective is in my reference file I have one column that is gene_id which is also present in the orginal gtf file. Now my simple goal is in m new gtf file I should add new attributes called Entrez_ID, so for that I have created the reference file which should be used to look for respective gene_id in the gtf file and when there is a match then it should add Entrez_ID tag and its value to the updated gtf file

Comment: Your code cannot work since in your sample data you have gene_id == ENSCAFG00845015183, which is not listed in your reference file.

Comment: so it can't ignore which is not matching and look for that is matching? since my file is big so I have given small subset which is consistent

Comment: Absolutly, we just cannot use your sample data to test our corrections or suggestions.

Comment: can you suggest me  how should i give the data?